# Send data to specific users (Missing error handler on socket)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I would like to send data to specific clients connected on the server.

I have this architecture :

```
chat = {
    rooms: [
        {
            users: [
                {
                    client: {/* socket.io client */},
                    pseudo: ''
                }
                ...
            ],
            messages: [...]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

I have currently the following code :

```
var chat = {
    // ...,
    sendMessagesTo: function(event, room) {
        var users = room.users;
        var msg = room.messages;
        var len = users.length;
        for (var i = len; i--;) {
            users[i].client.emit(event, msg);
        }
    },
}

io.on('connection', function(client) {

    // user = {client: client, pseudo: 'somePseudo'};
    // user is added in the chat > rooms > users array;

    chat.sendMessagesTo('newMessage', someSpecificRoom);

    // ...

});
```

But when I try to run the code (when the client sends a message), I have a server-side error : Missing error handler on `socket`.

I hope you have a solution :).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened. It worked with this solution :

```
io.to(users[i].client.id).emit(event, room.messages);
```

I stored the client.id with :

```
user = {client: {id: client.id}, pseudo: data.pseudo};
```